# Does Minecraft-pi Require an Internet Connection

Tags: internet, minecraft

This may sound stupid but I am new to Minecraft and when I tried to run minecraft in the terminal it said illegal instruction. Double clicking the Desktop shortcut does nothing. When I try to make a python script that uses the minecraft module(straight from pi magazine) it gives errors about ports and connections being refused. Do I need an internet connection to run Minecraft?

Comment: Include the text of the actual error(s).  SIGILL ("illegal instruction") can't be directly related to lack of a network, but it could be triggered by a code path in the application (Minecraft) that only runs in that context.  Ports and connections being refused is more likely (but not necessarily) to be about no internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minecraft pi may seem like a Minecraft port for Raspberry Pi allowing you to play multiplayer and use all of the functionality of Minecraft. However, looks can be decieving.

Instead, Minecraft Pi allows you to controll an environment with Python, in order to construct a world and understand code through the GUI of a simplified Minecraft.

Unless they push an update (`sudo apt-get update`, then `sudo apt-get upgrade`), you won't need internet.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Minecraft Pi doesn't require an internet connection to run.

Here is a article on how to install MC Pi you can always start from the beginning again if you can't work out what else to do. 
http://www.themagpi.com/issue/issue-11/article/minecraft-pi-edition/